# Very specific playing cards probability problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Six people are first handed one card each from a set of 52 cards. Then a seventh card is drawn and shown to each of the six players. Given that my card does not match the suit of the seventh card, what is the probability that at least one of the other five players' card matches the suit of the seventh card?

Ex.: Me and five others are handed one card each, mine is a six of hearts. Then an ace of diamonds is drawn as a seventh card and seen by everyone. What is the probability that at least one of the other players has a diamonds card in his hand (given that my card is not a diamond)?

What I have done is looked at P(someone else gets a heart | I dont get a heart)= P(Someone else gets a heart ∩ I dont get a heart)/P(I dont get a heart)

Where P(I dont get a heart) would be 1-12/51. I am having trouble distinguishing between P(someone else gets a heart | I dont get a heart) and P(Someone else gets a heart ∩ I dont get a heart). Have also tried messing around with this being a combinatorics problem without actually getting anywhere.

Comment: Exactly one or at least one with the same suit? Also could you edit your post to show your thoughts on this problem? What have you tried?

Comment: At least one. Will edit, thank you.

Comment: As a suggestion:  problems like this are often best approached backwards.  That is, compute the probability that $\textit {none}$ of the others have a card that matches the seventh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is handsome first to go for the probability that *none* of the other $5$ players has a card matching the suit of the seventh card.

If your card is e.g. of suit diamonds and the seventh card is a spade then the other players received cards from a deck containing $50$ cards of which $12$ are diamonds, $12$ are spades, $13$ are hearts and $13$ are clubs. Then the probability that none of them received a spade equals:$$\frac{\binom{12+13+13}{5}\binom{12}{0}}{\binom{50}{5}}=\frac{\binom{38}{5}}{\binom{50}{5}}$$

So the probability that at least one of them received a spade equals:$$1-\frac{\binom{38}{5}}{\binom{50}{5}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $\bar{M} = $ " The event that my card's suit does not match the 7'th card's suit.", $O_m = $ " The event that there's at least 1 other player whose card's suit matches that of the 7'th card."

We're interested in finding $P(O_m/\bar{M}).$

$$P(O_m/\bar{M}) = \frac{P(\bar{M}/O_m) \cdot P(O_m)}{P(\bar{M})}$$

Observe that $P(\bar{M}) = 1 - P(M)$ and $P(\bar{M}/O_m) = 1 - P({M}/O_m)$.

Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Sorry. I updated it now with it being at least one of the other players' card matches the suit, can I still use this? Thank you anyway.

Comment: Yes, you will only need to calculate $P(O_m)$ differently (You can do it by applying the complement: $P(O_m) = 1 - P(\bar{O_m})$) which is easier to find like others have noted. I will edit my answer, try to solve it this way.